# How to deploy java web app without creating war file to AWS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jakarta-ee, github

I've been uploading java app to AWS by extracting a war file from eclipse,

But now I've moved my code to github and,

I want to pull it from github onto my AWS server without generating a war file.

I've tried pulling it but it gives me an error. *The requested resource is not available.*

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=github%20aws%20deployment), mate. First result: [Tutorial: Deploy an Application from GitHub using AWS CodeDeploy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/github-integ-tutorial.html)

Comment: this doesn't work for java, i've tried.

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins or other CI tool. Jenkins will fetch code from GitHub, compile it and push it to AWS. You only need to specify deploy script.

Answer (score 0):

The [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) enthusiast within me suggests to automate the entire thing, going as far as creating an AWS CodePipeline with 3 steps:

(I have three of these pipelines active and am very happy I created them.)

1. Listen to GitHub repository for changes.
2. Pull latest repo changes and push code to a Jenkins instance
3. To save money on the Jenkins instance running 24/7 you could even create AWS Lambda functions to automate the starting up and shutting down of the Jenkins server
4. Output Jenkins artifact (your war file) to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

The AWS Documentation as with most services is pretty elaborate on this subject as is Jenkins'. You shouldn't have too much trouble setting this up and it'll save you a lot of time as the WAR file transfer between each step happens on the internal magically-high speed network of AWS.

It will cost some time to set up, especially if you're not that familiar with CI and this process but so very worth it to be familiar with these type of stacks.

Comment: Thanks this is all i needed.

Comment: If this answer helped to solve your problem, mark it as correct so other people with this issue can also find it.